# How to replace a value in json file using python

Tags: python, json, automation, yaml

My task is to replace a value in the json file.

my json file is below. Here I need to replace below values.

1. replace  "ServicePort": "0008", to value 0012
2. replace  "PService": "13.3.13.3",  to value  13.12.12.12
3. replace  "username": "root",  to "xyz"

My json file

```
{
  "version": "35.1",
  "ServicePort": "0008",
  "APIService": "14.414.4",
  "Storage": [
    {
      "PService": "13.3.13.3",
      "username": "root",
      "Number": 121,
      "IP": "10.2.10.2"
    }
  ]
}
```

My Python code to perform the above tasks is

```
import os
import sys
import json

with open('/xyz/Test/Conf.json', 'r') as fh:
    json_data = json.load(fh)

    for item in json_data:
        if item['Number'] in ["121"]:
            item['Number'] = "132"

with open('/xyz/Test/Conf.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(json_data, fh, indent=2)
```

here I am unable to do the same and hitting with the below error, may some please help me whats going wrong with my code.

Error:

```
    if item['Number'] in ["121"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Requirement 2:

I have to slightly modify the code.  the requirement is to create dictionary from the file which contains the json parameters and their values.

1. I have created a dictionary from the file called data
2. I need to change the value of json file by assigning the dictionary value as mentioned in the code below

change in the code - Assignment is from dictionary - which is not happening

```
D = {}
with open("data") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        D[key] = val
print(D)

for item in json_data:
    print(item, ": ", type(item))

print("-----------get keys and values from dict----------------")
for key, value in json_data.items():
    print(key, ": ", type(key), value, ": ", type(value))

print("----------try to change-----------------")
for key, value in json_data.items():
    if key == "Storage":
        for i in range(len(value)):
            if json_data["Storage"][i]["Number"] == 121:
                json_data["Storage"][i]["Number"] = D['Number']  #  <--- this is the change i need, may you please suggest any solution here, this assignment is not working

print(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for item in json_data:
    print(item, ": ", type(item))

print("-----------get keys and values from dict----------------")
for key, value in json_data.items():
    print(key, ": ", type(key), value, ": ", type(value))

print("----------try to change-----------------")
for key, value in json_data.items():
    if key == "Storage":
        for i in range(len(value)):
            if json_data["Storage"][i]["Number"] == 121:
                json_data["Storage"][i]["Number"] = 132

print(json_data)
```

Output:

```
version :  <class 'str'>
ServicePort :  <class 'str'>
APIService :  <class 'str'>
Storage :  <class 'str'>
-----------get keys and values from dict----------------
version :  <class 'str'> 35.1 :  <class 'str'>
ServicePort :  <class 'str'> 0008 :  <class 'str'>
APIService :  <class 'str'> 14.414.4 :  <class 'str'>
Storage :  <class 'str'> [{'PService': '13.3.13.3', 'username': 'root', 'Number': 121, 'IP': '10.2.10.2'}] :  <class 'list'>
----------try to change-----------------
{'version': '35.1', 'ServicePort': '0008', 'APIService': '14.414.4', 'Storage': [{'PService': '13.3.13.3', 'username': 'root', 'Number': 132, 'IP': '10.2.10.2'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks @dimay  if you see the output the value is not changed yet, it remained intact   see the last section in output   -->  'Number': 121,  it is supposed to be 132  but it shows 121.

Comment: Hi @umer. As for me everything works fine

Answer (score -1):

You can hardcode that

```
json_data['ServicePort'] = "0012"
json_data['PService'] = "13.12.12.12"
json_data["Storage"]["username"] = "xyz"
```